# chef installing node, npm and packages and running them

Tags: node.js, npm, chef-infra

I'm installing node and npm via the 'nodejs' cookbook and I'm including the recipe via

```
include_recipe "nodejs::npm"
```

I've installed the packages I want like so:

```
%w( dateformat aws2js optparse cloudwatch2graphite).each do |npm_package|
    nodejs_npm npm_package
end
```

and chef says that it's installed them successfully.

When I log onto the box and type `npm list` it simply returns empty no matter whether I'm as user `root` or user `vagrant`.

Why is the package list empty? Is it a user context issue?

Secondly how do I run a globally installed package such as`cloudwatch2graphite`.

When it's installed as a global package, do I just do

```
node cw2graphite.js
```

from any where to get it to run?

Bonus Points:

Just out of curiosity, what user does chef run as both on vagrant and on a box?

Comment: Chef generally executes as `root`, unless you specify differently with a [`user` attribute](https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html#attributes). I think the nodejs cookbooks also default to root; I remember having a lot of trouble getting them to execute as other users. On a final not, you should break out your questions about specific packages. Your `cloudwatch2graphite` questions should not be a part of this question and you'll get better, direct answers with a separate, appropriately phrased and tagged question.

Comment: Whilst I put `cloudwatch2graphite`, the question is really about how to run globally installed packages and how to deal with the package list being empty because It's getting in the way of me running a package. I will update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After poking around I realised what I was doing wrong.

with npm to do anything with a global package you have to use `-g` it's obvious in hindsight but I'm not much a node person so It's an easy mistake to make.

So to list global packages it's:

```
npm -g list
```

However whilst to run a script your supposed to do:

```
npm -g run <package-name> <package-script>
```

Nothing happened when I tried to use it to start cloudwatch2graphite.

That said, I was able to get it working by doing:

```
node `npm -g root`/<package-name>/<script-name>.js
```

Comment: The weirdness is because that package isn’t designed to be installed globally. Packages that are designed to be installed globally generally ship with a binary, so you could just do `$ cw2graphite whatever`. This is not one of those.

Comment: Fair enough, but cloudwatch2graphite is supposed to be used as an app but didn't seem to come with an executable, so what else was I supposed to?